# Grouped UITableView corner radius default value

Tags: ios, default, rounded-corners, uitableview

I am customizing some `UITableViewCell`'s background and I'd like to set the same corner radius as they have by default when the style of the table view is grouped. `[self.tableView.layer cornerRadius]` returns me a 0, could somebody tell me what the default value is or how could I get it?

Answer (score 3):

Default corner radius of Inset Grouped UITableView cell is **10**.

[image]

Comment: Please don’t post code as a screenshot. Instead, post code as text, and format as code using the editor.

Comment: This is not code. Screeshot is fine here

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to import QuartzCore:

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

than, for rounding the corners of something all you need to do is:

```
myTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

**OR** if for single cell, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

add:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I didn't explain myself, I just wanted to know what the default value of `cornerRadius` is when you simply set a tableView as grouped, in order to set that same `cornerRadius` to my custom cells

Comment: i don't think there is a default.. it is probebly 0. when you call the function cornerRadius you need to say what is the number... it's just like setting an integer, you cant just: [self int] and excpect something to happend